# Changing the default directory of Anaconda (where conda installs packages and creates environments)?

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm looking for a way to change the default directory where Anaconda creates and stores virtual environments as well as installed packages. The default directory is the .conda directory in my C:/Users/ directory however this poses problems since this directory has strict permission limits on modification so I need Anaconda to create virtual environments in a specific directory. I can think of a couple ways to do this.

1/ Modifying the target directories of Anaconda Prompt in its Properties. (I haven't tried this yet since this requires admin authorization).

2/ Using -prefix

```
conda create --prefix ./envs jupyterlab=0.35 matplotlib=3.1 numpy=1.16
```

However, I wonder if there is a way to permanently change the default directory of Anaconda ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the `envs_dirs` and `pkgs_dirs` configuration options in [the documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-env-directories). Note they can also be set with `conda config`.

Comment: The beauty of solution 2 is that it allows you to have separate environments for each project.